# Gargoyle repeater bridge channel hopping

Tags: linux, wifi, openwrt, router

I have the Linux-based Gargoyle firmware running on an old TP-Link router, serving as a Repeater bridge to extend the range of a WIFI access point.

Do I need to lock the original access point to a single channel, or will the firmware correctly change channels if the source access point changes?